OpenSSH dynamic port forwarding from server to client
Is there a way to create a SOCKS5 proxy on the OpenSSH server side that proxies traffic to the SSH client?
I know there is ssh -D but this only can forward requests from the client to the server.
There is also ssh -R but this can only forward requests to a specific port from the server to the client.

-R also takes a single port number, in which case it requests the server to provide SOCKS5 service. This was added in OpenSSH 7.6 (server and client).
Starting with OpenSSH 8.5, the client's PermitRemoteOpen option controls which destinations the server is allowed to access.

I believe the implementation is in the client only and it works with any SSH server that normally supports (regular, former) ssh -R. The point is the server listens and forwards like with any -R. It doesn't matter if forwarded packets leave ssh on the local side and go to a port, a socket, or don't leave and get handled internally by ssh -- all this happens on the client and the server does not care. Am I wrong?

You can achieve dynamic port forwarding from the server to the client in OpenSSH by using a combination of reverse port forwarding (ssh -R) and SOCKS proxy functionality. While ssh -D creates a SOCKS5 proxy on the client, the typical ssh -R usage doesn’t support dynamic port forwarding by itself.
However, you can run a SOCKS proxy server on the client side and then reverse-forward the client’s SOCKS5 proxy port to the server.
Run a SOCKS5 proxy on the client:
You can use tools like ssh -D, dante-server, or socksify to run a SOCKS5 proxy on the client. If you use ssh -D, you can run this on the client to set up a local SOCKS proxy:ssh -D 1080 localhost
This will set up a SOCKS5 proxy on port 1080 of the client.
Reverse forward the SOCKS port from the client to the server:
Next, you'll use ssh -R to reverse forward the port from the client to the server. Assuming you are already logged into the server via SSH, you can run the following command to reverse forward the SOCKS5 proxy port (1080) from the client to the server:
ssh -R 9999:localhost:1080 user@server
In this case, the server is listening on port 9999, which is being forwarded to the SOCKS proxy running on the client’s port 1080.
Use the SOCKS proxy on the server:
Now, from the server, you can point applications to localhost:9999, which will forward the traffic dynamically to the client’s SOCKS proxy.
ssh -D 1080 localhost: Sets up a SOCKS5 proxy on the client machine.
ssh -R 9999:localhost:1080: Forwards port 9999 on the server to the client’s port 1080 (the SOCKS5 proxy).
This setup effectively allows the server to send traffic back to the client, dynamically routed through the SOCKS proxy. If my advice did not help you, then it is worth to ask for help from professionals in software development, which from their experience could advise you and give a solution to this problem https://tech-stack.com/services/custom-software-development
